# Using WebKit in React Native shows only white screen

Tags: react-native, webkit

I have updated React Native from 0.55 to 0.57.0 to use the updated web kit webview on iOS.

```js
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
```

However, when useWebKit is set to true, the page does not display properly. If I set it to false, the page renders as it should. This worked fine on 0.55, am I missing something? Here is my render method:

```js
render() {
        return (
                <WebView
                    ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
                    allowFileAccess={true}
                    originWhitelist={["*"]}
                    source={{ uri: "index.html" }}
                    onError={console.error.bind(console, 'error')}
                    bounces={false}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    useWebKit={true}
                    onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
                />
        )   
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `style={{ flex: 1}}`.

Comment: Thanks, I added `style={{ flex: 1}}` and still get the same result

Comment: It's because of `source={{ uri: "index.html" }}`, this needs to point to HTML file, right now it's a string. Try `source={ require('path/to/your/html') }`.

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same result. I am using onNavigationStateChange to log the url it is going to, and it seems to start/end loading the correct url both ways. The index file runs some javascript that was minified and bundled with the app, maybe webKit handles that differently?